# How to align terms in polynomials in display math?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I'd like to align the terms of some polynomials in display math. For example, in the following:

```
\begin{align}
    e &= x^5                   + x     \\
    f &= x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 \\
    g &=       x^4       + x^2     + 1 \\
    h &= x^5       + x^3 + x^2 + x     \\
    i &=       x^4 + x^3               \\
\end{align}
```

I'd like it to appear as the alignment is in the code. But I cannot seem to figure out where to place the ampersands to get this right. Can someone help?

Comment: `alignat` is your environment. Also, there's `systeme` package, that may help you.

Comment: Do you need a number for each line?

Comment: @egreg No, I don't. No need to number any of the equations.

Answer (score 3):

Boring to type, but effective

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % like cases
\begin{array}{
  r
  >{{}}c<{{}} % equals
  r % degree 5
  >{{}}c<{{}} % plus
  r % degree 4
  >{{}}c<{{}} % plus
  r % degree 3
  >{{}}c<{{}} % plus
  r % degree 2
  >{{}}c<{{}} % plus
  r % degree 1
  >{{}}c<{{}} % plus
  r % degree 0
}
e & = & x^5 &   &     &   &     &   &     &   &   & + & 1 \\
f & = & x^5 & + & x^4 & + & x^3 & + & x^2 & + & x & + & 1 \\
g & = &     &   & x^4 &   &     & + & x^2 &   &   & + & 1 \\
h & = & x^5 &   &     & + & x^3 & + & x^2 & + & x &   &   \\
i &=  &     &   & x^4 & + & x^3 &   &     &   &   &   &
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The intercolumn space is set to zero, the spacing is obtained by adding empty atoms around the relation and operation signs.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the reasons why I use `mathenv` rather than `amsmath`:
More flexible equation arrays.
This example is very much like egreg's, but shorter,
and with the option that omitting the `*` gives you numbered equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathenv}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}[r*{6}{>{{}}l<{{}}r}]
e & = & x^5 &   &     &   &     &   &     &   &   & + & 1 \\
f & = & x^5 & + & x^4 & + & x^3 & + & x^2 & + & x & + & 1 \\
g & = &     &   & x^4 &   &     & + & x^2 &   &   & + & 1 \\
h & = & x^5 &   &     & + & x^3 & + & x^2 & + & x &   &   \\
i &=  &     &   & x^4 & + & x^3 &   &     &   &   &   &
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Mathenv eqnarray output]

Comment: In case of coefficients, I think the alignment should be  `r` rather than `l`.

Comment: @Bernard: The `l` is for the signs, and in case of coeffs I'd enter them with the signs, such as `&+2&`. Which is why I chose `l` rather than egreg's `c` to keep signs aligned in such cases.

Comment: Also feasible: If coeffs -- except their signs -- are written with the monomials, then those get right-aligned. Might be better for numbers with variable-length integer part.

Answer (score 2):

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `alignat` can also do this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{7}
  e & ={} & x^5 &       &     &       &     &       &     &       &   & {}+{} & 1 \\
  f & ={} & x^5 & {}+{} & x^4 & {}+{} & x^3 & {}+{} & x^2 & {}+{} & x & {}+{} & 1 \\
  g & ={} &     &       & x^4 &       &     & {}+{} & x^2 &       &   & {}+{} & 1 \\
  h & ={} & x^5 &       &     & {}+{} & x^3 & {}+{} & x^2 & {}+{} & x &       &   \\
  i & ={} &     &       & x^4 & {}+{} & x^3 &       &     &       &   &       &
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```